# basic usage of node , pubnub ,socket.io not working

Tags: pubnub, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to use socket.io with pubnub. I am not able to understand how to get data on client(index.html) which I have published on the server.Below is the sample code.

my server.js

```
var pubnub = require("pubnub")

var p = pubnub.init({
  "subscribe_key" : "xxxx",
 "publish_key" : "xxxx",
 "params" : {},
});

 p.publish({
  "message" : "foo",
  "channel" : "test_channel",
 });
```

client code - index.html

```
  <script src="http://cdn.pubnub.com/socket.io.min.js"></script>
  <script>(function(){
   // IMPORTANT: PubNub Setup with Account
   var pubnub_setup = {
      channel       : 'test_channel',
      publish_key   : 'xxxx',
     subscribe_key : 'xxxx'
     };

   var socket = io.connect( 'http://pubsub.pubnub.com/', pubnub_setup );

   socket.on( 'connect', function() {
    console.log('Connection Established! Ready to send/receive data!');
   } );

   socket.on( 'message', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
   } );

   socket.on( 'disconnect', function() {
    console.log('my connection dropped');
   } );


   socket.on( 'reconnect', function() {
    console.log('my connection has been restored!');
   } );

 })();</script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the PubNub Socket.io SDK and not the PubNub Node SDK?

Comment: No specific reason... Used pubnub node SDK now...was able to make it work..Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for reporting back and happy to hear it is working for you. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Socket.io SDK

As stated in this [other Stack Overflow thread, the PubNub Socket.IO SDK for PubNub is designed for people that started with socket.io but want to migrate to PubNub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393828/socket-io-with-pubnub-why). Otherwise, there is no requirement to use Socket.IO SDK if you are starting with PubNub first and you should use the latest [PubNub Node SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) and [PubNub JavaScript SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) or [whatever PubNub SDK you require](https://www.pubnub.com/docs).

And the newly implemented, ES5 compliant [PubNub JavaScript/Node v4 SDKs (currently in beta)](https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/tree/develop) are coming soon!